# running php script inside virtual directories centos

Tags: php, centos, virtualhost

I am having a devil of a time trying to get PHP scripts to run inside virtual directories on a CentOS web server. The server has a LAMP install and phpMyAdmin.

The server has virtual directores. These virtual directories are located at /home/sitename. eg. /home/site1  /home/site2  /home/site3

The simple phpinfo script will run:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

But when I try to run:

```
<?php
passthru(id);
?>
```

or:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST WRITE FILE</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<body>
<?php 
$myFile = "test.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "TEST1\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = "TEST2\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

They refuse to do anything.

I have created a group named www-hosting and this group is the owner of all the /home/sitename directories. I have confirmed that PHP is trying to run as user apache. I have added user apache to the group www-hosting. As part of my testing I have changed the permission on /home/site1 to 775 to allow the group www-hosting rwx but still my PHP script will not run.

I have searched online but been unable to find an answer as to why PHP will not execute.

I'm sure it's some kind of permissions issue, and I would be so grateful if someone could assist with an answer to get this running properly.

Comment: Your script is running... it's just crashing due to the permissions problem.  Turn on error logging and see what the specific problem is.

Comment: Many thanks for your assistance  @Brad .  I have checked the logs and I do not see any entry regarding the Test Write File. I do however see entries for the info.php file that does successfully run. Interestingly, an additional file also ran OK (based on the display on the webpage, and its inclusion in the log file.  `<?php  system('whoami');  ?>`  I've continued Googling, but as yet to no avail.